# Glype Proxy configuration

Tags: php, web-services, web, proxy, config

I am trying to setup a web proxy so I can bypass the web filter. I am using Glype proxy php script but the web filter detected it and blocked it. Is there any way I can config or edit the script so the web filter would not be able to detect my proxy?

Answer (score 0):

You have to rename the file browse.php and all references to it. Here is explained how: http://glypetemplates.com/rename-browse.php-to-prevent-abuse-from-automated-scripts.html

Two useful hints:

- Avoid the name 'proxy' in your url. This might trigger someone's attention (or a script that scans for this term) which will make sure that the url is quickly added to the blacklist.
- If you have already been blocked you are probably on a blacklist from which you won't be removed. Therefor, try to put your proxy on a new url (e.g. if your previous url was `example.com/secret` now try `example.com/randomWord`).

A bit of background information: The following article gives a nice overview of what companies can do to detect proxy sites: http://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/detection/detecting-preventing-anonymous-proxy-usage-32943

It is a bit outdated (2008) but what it says is that the Glype is detected by looking at the link the user is browsing to. Since this is always of the same format (`browse.php?u=....`):

> To block or detect any usage of a Glype anonymous proxy server, use
>   the following regular  expression:  `(browse\.php\?u=).+(&b).*`

Renaming browse.php will solve this problem. This is assuming your webfilter is not using any more advanced techniques...

Comment: Thanks, I currently can't access my computer but I will try that later.

Comment: You're welcome. I also just added two useful hints, those can be rather important when you give it a new chance.

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't work. My school often update their firewall now.

Comment: Did you follow the hints I provided? These are essential. If you did, one other way that glype could be detected is by its footer with credentials. Removing it is a bit complicated but it is explained clearly [here](http://forum.my-proxy.com/glype-v12-nolicence-and-no-glype-link-t14767.0.html;wap2=) (Again, it is essential that you put this on a new url!!)

Comment: Your new link is blocked by school filter

Comment: Looks like you are on the right track in that case ;) Try to fix it from a pc outside your school network, and try again. I hope it works.

Comment: The filter doesn't block the index page, just the brower.php code(which I have change the file name to 'go.php'

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't have any more solutions in my pocket. Maybe somebody else has. Or you could try to find a less popular proxy, there are really thousands of them and they can't all be on the blacklist of your school. Good luck!